# Boost asio exits with code 0 for no reason. Setting a breakpoint AFTER the problematic statement solves it

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I'm writing a TCP server-client pair with boost asio. It's very simple and synchronous.

The server is supposed to transmit a large amount of binary data through several recursive calls to a function that transmits a packet of data over TCP. The client does the analogue, reading and appending the data through a recursive function that reads incoming packets from the socket.

However, in the middle of receiving this data, most times (around 80%) the client just stops recursion suddenly, always before one of the read calls (shown below). It shouldn't be able to do this, given that there are several other statements and function calls after the recursion.

```
size_t bytes_transferred = m_socket.read_some(boost::asio::buffer(m_fileReadBuffer, m_fileReadBuffer.size()));
```

m_fileReadBuffer is a boost::array of char, with size 4096 (although I have tried other buffer formats as well with no success).

There is absolutely no way I can conceive of deducing why this is happening.

- The program exits immediately, so I can't pass an error code to read_some and read any error messages, since that would need to happen after the read_some statement
- No exceptions are thrown
- No errors or warnings on compile/runtime
- If I put breakpoints inside the recursive function, the problem never happens (transfer completes successfully)
- If I put breakpoints after the transfer, or trap the execution in a while loop after the transfer, the problem never happens and there is no sign of anything wrong

Also, it's important to note that the server ALWAYS successfully sends all the data. On top of that, the problem always happens at the very end of transmissions: I can send 8000 bytes and it will exit when around 6000  or 7000 bytes have been transferred, and I can send 8000000 bytes and it will exit when something like 7996000 bytes have been transferred.

I can provide any code necessary, I just have no idea of where the problem could be. Below is the recursive read function on the client:

```
void TCP_Client::receive_volScan_message()
{
    try
    {
        //If the transfer is complete, exit this loop
        if(m_rollingSum >= (std::streamsize)m_fileSize)
        {
            std::cout << "File transfer complete!\n";
            std::cout << m_fileSize << " "<< m_fileData.size() << "\n\n";               

            return;
        }

        boost::system::error_code error;        

        //Transfer isn't complete, so we read some more        
        size_t bytes_transferred = m_socket.read_some(boost::asio::buffer(m_fileReadBuffer, m_fileReadBuffer.size()));

        std::cout << "Received " << (std::streamsize)bytes_transferred << " bytes\n"; 

        //Copy the bytes_transferred to m_fileData vector. Only copies up to m_fileSize bytes into m_fileData
        if(bytes_transferred+m_rollingSum > m_fileSize) 
        {
            //memcpy(&m_fileData[m_rollingSum], &m_fileReadBuffer, m_fileSize-m_rollingSum);
            m_rollingSum += m_fileSize-m_rollingSum;
        }
        else
        {
           // memcpy(&m_fileData[m_rollingSum], &m_fileReadBuffer, bytes_transferred);
            m_rollingSum += (std::streamsize)bytes_transferred;  
        }                     

        std::cout << "rolling sum: " << m_rollingSum << std::endl;

        this->receive_volScan_message();
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        std::cout << "whoops";
    }                
}
```

As a suggestion, I have tried changing the recursive loops to for loops on both the client and server. The problem persists, somehow. The only difference is that now instead of exiting 0 before the previously mentioned read_some call, it exits 0 at the end of one of the for loop blocks, just before it starts executing another for loop pass.

EDIT: As it turns out, the error doesn't take place whenever I built the client in debug mode on my IDE.

Comment: _'through several recursive calls'_ This doesn't sound right. Why it has to be recursive?

Comment: Might be some timing issue or possibly [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) somewhere? Or maybe it's just that there are *too many* recursions so that you fill up the stack, and the call causes a stack overflow which crashes the program?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ It's a simple way of doing it. The function checks to see if all the data has been transferred, if not, it sends some data and calls itself.

Comment: @Daniel A simple loop would suffice to do so. I still don't see any point for using recursion.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I tested for timing issues with large delays between send and receive messages, it still happened. Also, I'm testing with small files, so there are usually 3 or 4 recursive calls, and an overflow like that surely wouldn't pass unnoticed

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ If I can't fix this, changing it to a loop would be a possible course of action. However this could be a symptom of another problem somewhere that could still remain present, so I would like to find out the root of the problem

Comment: @Daniel There's a good chance, the recursion is the actual source of the problem :-/ ...

Comment: How are you maintaining the lifetime of the array. The array should be in memory until the transfer is finished.

Comment: Also, make sure you are throttling your data some how. A mistake I made was to keep pushing stuff into the kernel buffer with write some and not waiting for the client to catch up. I ended up running out of memory.

Comment: @nishantjr m_fileReadBuffer is a class member variable, and the function called recursively to read is a class member function. That shouldn't be the problem. Also, I've done that before and it's a very vocal error, wouldn't just exit 0 out of nowhere. As for the throttling idea: I have tried adding 1 second delays between packets, and I can see it's way more than enough time for the client to follow. As soon as one of the last packets is sent and the client reads it, it exits zero.

Comment: Read_some is synchronous. This wont be running in you io_service.run

Comment: How are you detecting end of transfer? Bytes ==0 won't work

Comment: @nishantjr I keep a rolling sum that adds bytes_transferred with every call. When that sum is >= the expected file size, it detects the end of transfer. I can guarantee the rolling sum and file size numbers are being calculated correctly also

Comment: Can you post the recursive read function. (I feel it really should be a simple for loop)

Comment: I edited the main post with the recursive read function. In retrospect It does really feel like a for loop should be better. The rolling sum variable and the way the recursion ends are essentially a big for loop

Comment: Where is m_FileSize updated? The if condition at the end seems redundant. Try to avoid having data duplicated (`m_fileSize` and `m_fileData.size()`)

Comment: m_fileSize is already set before the first instance of that recursive function is called. It has the complete file size

Comment: Hmmm, not sure what's doing on. It's not an issue with asio calls. There's something missing. Seems like a logic error in the counter or completion checking logic, not with the asio calls, but I can't find it.

Comment: I changed the recursive function calls to a for loop, but the exact same problem persists. At random times, when it tries to do a read, it somehow manages to exit the entire program with code 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't completely understood the problem, however I have managed to fix it entirely.

The root of the issue was that on the client, the `boost::asio::read` calls *made main exit with code 0 if the server messages hadn't arrived yet*. That means that a simple

```
while(m_socket.available() == 0)
{
    ;
}
```

before all read calls completely prevented the problem. Both in debug and release mode.

This is very strange because as I understand these functions should just block until there is something to read, and even if they encountered errors they should return zero.

I think the debug/release discrepancy happened because the `m_readBuffer` wasn't initialized to anything whenever the read calls took place. This made the `read` call return some form of silent error. On debug, uninitialized variables get automatically set to `NULL`, stealthily fixing my problem.

I have no idea why adding a while loop *after* the transfer prevented the issue, though. Neither why it normally happened on the *end* of transfers, after the m_readBuffer had been set and successfully used several times.

On top of that, I have never seen this type of "crash" before, where the program simply exits with code 0 in a random place, with no errors or exceptions thrown.

Comment: This doesn't seem like the correct solution. How does your client know how much data to expect from the server?

Comment: @SamMiller The file always has a constant size header that carries info such as file size.

The while(m_socket.available() == 0) call happens while the client waits to read this header, and again while it waits to read the file contents (that come right after).

I still don't understand why the read functions don't naturally block until there is data to read, like they are supposed to

Comment: The read functions indeed perform blocking operations as requested, I suspect your problem lies elsewhere as you haven't posted a [sscce](http://sscce.org).